# How would you animate elastic compression?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate a prosthetic foot of this kind

https://www.oapl.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/homepage_main_block_286x308/public/Elan%2005small.jpg?itok=0hNvnXbp

How would you approach the animation of a step, considering the compression of the foot and the spring like motion of the tip and the heel?

What is the common way to animate elastic componets such as the ones in the picture?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Do you have an animation of what are you tring to animate as reference? It would be very helpful if you could post it.

Comment: Hi @pedozzi1, this doesn't really fit the [ask] and [tour] advice, specifically the question is subjective.  Also I have too many pending edits, so I can't fix your formatting, but feel free to edit it yourself and make your question shine :)